# List index out of error when parsing html with bs4 and pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I have a directory with many sub-directories that some of them contain html files. Every time i find an html file i want to parse the data into a pandas dataframe. The thing is, that I am getting this error "IndexError: list index out of range"
My code is this:

```
or root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir):
list_file_path = os.path.join(root, 'my-directory-list.txt')

with open(list_file_path, 'wb') as list_file:
    for subdir in subdirs:

      for filename in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)



        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            f_content = f.read()



            #Check if file is html
            check_html = bool(BeautifulSoup(f_content, "lxml").find())
            #If it is HTML

            if check_html == True:
              print ("It's html")
              soup = BeautifulSoup(f_content, 'lxml')
              table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
              df = pd.read_html(str(table))
              print(tabulate(df[0]))





            #If it is not HTML 
            else:
              print ("its not")
```

I know that my error is the df[0] in this line `table = soup.find_all('table')[0]` but I do not know how to cope with it.

Also the html files I am trying to parse usually look like this(the first line) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="no-js"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> <title>   text1 </title>
```

and in some cases they also contains tables. 
Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `table = soup.find_all('table')[0]` is returning `None`. How you have said that sometimes it can have tables and sometimes not, you have to deal with the exception. A simple verification `if table:` might be enough.

```
if check_html == True:
          print ("It's html")
          soup = BeautifulSoup(f_content, 'lxml')
          table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
          if table:
               df = pd.read_html(str(table))
               print(tabulate(df[0]))
```